# Rails: Devise: Undefined Method `username'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When using devise I keep getting this error when I try to load the sign up page with the new field "username"

```
undefined method `username' for #<User:0x007f8c8e347f48>
```

This is in devise under registrations:

```
3: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
4:   <%= f.error_notification %>
5: 
6: <%= f.input :username %>
7: <%= f.input :email %>
8: <%= f.input :password %>
9: <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
```

This is in models in user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
 # attr_accessible :title, :body
 end
```

To set it up I put the following commands through terminal:

```
rails generate migration AddUsernameToUsers username:string
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Through previous questions I put these commands through terminal:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

The error doesn't let me even access the page. Unlike other questions where it happens after you click sign up.

**Edit**

After restarting my server a few times it is now automatically exiitng the local server with this error:

```
Called from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-     3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': /Users/hunter/first_app/app/models/view.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

**Edit**

This is in models/view.rb:

```
class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

**Edit**

I removed the comma at the end of :remember_me in models/view.rb and now the server works. I can now load it on localhost:3000. However, when I click the sign up page I get the same error as before.

Comment: if `resource` is not an instance of `User`, you are in big trouble.

Comment: I just started learning Rails, how do I check if that's the case and  how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted your server after migration?

Comment: you're trying to use username as an auth. key rather than default one(email) ?

Comment: My server is now automatically exiting, I posted the error message above, maybe this was the problem all along?

Comment: This last error is more than probably caused because you are missing an `end` somewhere.

Comment: @Gmat any idea where I would find where I'm missing an `end`?

Comment: show us the contents of models/view.rb

Comment: @AlthafHamez I added it above!

Answer (score 1):

If you want login using either your username or password, you have a very good explanation over here: [Devise login using your username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

If you want to login only using your username, you'll have to change your authentication_key from your devise.rb configuration file:

```
  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

Also you'll have to modify your registration and session views according to your authentication_key.

In devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
3: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
4: <%= f.error_notification %>
5:
6: <%= f.input :username %>
7: <%= f.input :password %>
8: <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
9:
10: <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
```

In devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:

```
3: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
4: <%= f.error_notification %>
5:
6: <%= f.input :username %>
```

In devise/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
3: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
4:
5: <%= f.input :username %>
6: <%= f.input :password %>
7:
8: <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
```

Comment: So is this the solution to my problem? Will it work if I do this?

Comment: I went through the whole walkthrough, and it didn't work, when I got to :username it gave me the same error. `undefined method 'username' for #<User:0x007ff1ee1a0648>`

Comment: Did you change the devise views according to your authentication_key?

Comment: Newbie question, how would I do that?

Comment: You'll have to change the following views from your app: devise/sessions/new.html.erb , devise/registrations/edit.html.erb , devise/registrations/new.html.erb . I'll edit my answer according to this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I thought to share my answer as I was getting the same error. The migration is not enough. You need to add this bit of code to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
end
```

This will do the trick.